# Python 3.7 Problema Print valor String devuelto por una Funcion

Tags: python, string, funciones, print, python-3.7

Benas a todos compañeros.
Estoy aprendiendo python y practicando la Herencia en POO me surgió este problema que no lo e podido solucionar:

**Codigo:**

```py
class Animal:  #Clase principal
    Sexo = ""
    Peso = 0
    Altura = 0

    def comer():
        return "El animal a comido"

    def setsexo(self, S):
        self.Sexo = S


    def reproducirse():
        return "El animal se a reproducido"

    def morir():
        return "El animal a muerto pero revivio para que sigas experimentando con la herencia"

class Perro(Animal): #Clase que hereda de la clase animal

    def correr():
        return "El perro corre"

class Pajaro(Animal):

    def volar():
        return "El pajaro esta volando"

#----------------------------

Laica = Perro
print(Laica.correr())
print(Laica.comer())
print("---------------------")

lechuza= Pajaro
S = lechuza.morir
print(str(S))
print(lechuza.reproducirse)
print(lechuza.volar)
```

Al ejecutar ese codigo, los print que deberian devolver los strings que retorno de las funciones, me devuelven lo siguiente:

```
El perro corre
El animal a comido
---------------------
<function Animal.morir at 0x04268150>
<function Animal.reproducirse at 0x04268108>
<function Pajaro.volar at 0x042681E0>
```

En algunos casos me devuelve bien los valores String y en otros no, y no puedo encontrar por que sucede eso.
Espero que puedan ayudarme y desde ya
  Muchísimas Gracias :)

Comment: No estás invocando a los métodos, pues te falta poner `()` al final de sus nombres. Por tanto lo que imprimen esos `print` no es el resultado de llamar al método, sino que imprimen _el propio método_ (y lo que ves es que son funciones, cómo se llaman, y en qué dirección están guardadas)

Comment: Además, `Laica=Perro` no está creando un objeto nuevo de tipo `Perro`. Para hacer eso debes poner `laica = Perro()` (es costumbre usar minúsculas para los nombres de variables, y reservar mayúsculas sólo para nombres de funciones, pero ese no es el problema aquí, sino los paréntesis tras `Perro()`). Con esos paréntesis llamas al _constructor_ de la clase, y obtienes un objeto. Sin esos paréntesis no llamas al constructor, y lo que obtienes es una referencia a la clase. Te funciona porque (otro error) no declaraste el parámetro `self` que deben llevar todos los métodos de la clase.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Me ayudaron mucho las respuestas. Ahora me voy a poner a investigar mas sobre el self

Comment: He escrito una respuesta más extensa explicando los detalles sobre estas cosas que tenías mal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código tiene varios errores.

## ¿Por qué los print del final no salen como los primeros?

En los primeros pusiste algo como:

```
print(Laica.correr())
```

lo que causa la ejecución del método `correr` de la variable `Laica`. Ese método retorna una cadena, y eso es lo que `print()` imprime.

En los del final en cambio pusiste algo como:

```
print(lechuza.volar)
```

en los que olvidaste los paréntesis que causan la invocación del método, con lo que *no estás llamando a `lechuza.volar`*, sino que estás directamente imprimiendo el valor de la variable `lechuza.volar`, que es una función. Por eso en la salida ves el mensaje que te dice que es una función, cuál es su nombre, y en qué dirección está almacenada.

Para llamar a la función y así imprimir la cadena que devuelve debería ser:

```
print(lechuza.volar())
```

## Errores de OOP

Pero el código tiene más errores, de concepto, sobre programación orientada a objetos en Python.

En Python, todos los métodos de una clase han de llevar **obligatoriamente** un primer parámetro que representa al objeto sobre el que actúan. Es costumbre llamar a ese primer parámetro `self`. Uno de tus métodos (`setSexo()`) lo tiene , pero el resto no y eso está mal.

Por otro lado, no *instancias* las clases. Se dice *instanciar* una clase a la creación de un objeto de esa clase. Tienes la clase `Perro`, que es una especie de plantilla a partir de la cual crear múltiples perros (instancias), de modo que cada una de esas instancias pueda tener diferentes atributos (por ejemplo, uno podría ser macho, otro podría ser hembra, tener diferente peso, altura, etc.) pero todos tendrían los mismos comportamientos a través de sus métodos.

Para instanciar un objeto de una clase se usa la sintaxis `NombreDeClase()` y dentro de los paréntesis irían los parámetros que se le pasarían al *constructor* de esa clase. En tu caso no has programado un constructor, de modo que no necesitas pasar parámetros, pero sí los paréntesis. Si los omites, como aquí:

```
laika = Perro
```

no estarás creando un nuevo perro, sino haciendo que la variable `laika` sea una referencia directa a la clase. Es decir, a partir de este punto `laika` es lo mismo que `Perro`, una clase y no una instancia (de hecho, en tu caso, podrías hacer `laika()` para construir una instancia, pero sería tremendamente confuso). Lo correcto sería:

```
laika = Perro()
```

Cuando más adelante hagas `laika.correr()`, estarás llamando al método `correr()` de la clase `Perro` y Python le pasará automáticamente como primer parámetro el objeto sobre el que debe actuar. Es decir, en `self`, recibirá `laika`. Eso permite al método, actuando sobre `self`, cambiar algún atributo, de modo que ese cambio afecte sólo a ese perro en particular (laika) y no otros que puedas haber creado, aunque sean de la misma clase. A fin de cuentas, cada perro (instancia) tiene sus propios atributos (sexo, altura, peso...) independientes de los demás perros (instancias).

Y eso me lleva al tercer error. Has declarado `Sexo`, `Peso` y `Altura` como *atributos de clase*, puesto que los has escrito al inicio de la clase `Perro` y fuera de todo método. Esto no es lo que quieres, ya que los atributos de clase son compartidos por todas las instancias de la clase, y tú quieres que cada perro particular pueda tener diferentes valores en ellas. Por tanto *no hay que escribirlos ahí*, sino inicializarlos en el constructor.

### Otros detalles

El uso de mayúsculas/minúsculas en python es libre, pero hay unos convenios que todo el mundo respeta:

- Los nombres de clases tienen la primera letra mayúscula
- Los métodos y atributos de clases y objetos, así como las variables de programa son todo minúsculas y si son varias palabras `van_asi`.

### Resolvamos todos estos problemas

```py
class Animal:  #Clase principal
    # No ponemos atributos de clase

    def __init__(self, sexo="", altura=0, peso=0):
        # El constructor inicializa los atributos del objeto
        self.sexo = sexo   # A partir de lo que reciba como parámetros
        self.altura = altura
        self.peso = peso

    def comer(self):  # Añadir el parámetro self que faltaba
        return "El animal ha comido"

    def setsexo(self, s):
        self.sexo = s

    def reproducirse(self):
        return "El animal se ha reproducido"

    def morir(self):
        return "El animal ha muerto pero revivio para que sigas experimentando con la herencia"

class Perro(Animal): #Clase que hereda de la clase animal

    def correr(self):
        return "El perro corre"
```

Y ahora puedes inicializar diferentes perros así:

```
laika = Perro("H", 50, 30)  # Los parámetros que le pases inicializarán los atributos
rintintin = Perro("M", 70, 40)
```